# Unable to start debugger in Nuclide Atom

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

trying to run react native debugger in atom editor, but got this error.

Process exited (Port: 8081 (React Native))
Nuclide Debugger
20:08:34

[image]